# Infinite Probability Space of Real Numbers

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, infinite-groups

I have a question on my homework that I'm very befuddled about.

Find a value of a constant $c$ such that the formula $p(n)=\frac{c}{3^n}$ defines a probability distribution on the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ of all natural numbers. (Enter your answer as a decimal.)

I don't even know where to begin. All I can assume is that the probability should be equal for each real number. If there were $10$ numbers, each would have a $.1$ probability but the fact that this is infinite really confuses me especially since it has to satisfy this expression.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are not asked to define a probability on the reals, but rather on the naturals. Secondly, you seem to be under the impression that any two points should be assigned equal probability density, but that is not required at all. Note that $p(n)=\frac{c}{3^n}$ is already given, and that you are only asked to find the value of $c$ such that this will give a probability distribution. So, what property should a probability distribution on the *naturals* satisfy? In particular, $1=\sum ....$

Comment: okay sorry if i'm a little slow on this clarification. The probability function given defines the probability of a selecting a real number n. That makes sense. I'm just confused on how to think about choosing or even solving for c. I just know the summation of all the probabilities should equal 1

Comment: what condition on the individual assignment of probability densities must be satisfied? Can you define $p(n)=15$ for all $n$? would that be a probability distribution? Look up the definition of probability distribution.

Comment: the two conditions are the summation equals 1 and each p(n) must be between 0 and 1. As long as c is less than 3^n, than the probability of any number will be less than 1

Comment: would i be calculating an integral of the function from 0 to infinity to find c?

Comment: yes, now don't just ignore what you just said about the summation equals 1. Would any choice for $c$ make sure the sum will be one, or maybe just once value? Compute the sum using $c$, equate it to $1$ and voila, an equation to solve.

Comment: a sum over the natural numbers, not an integral over the reals.

Comment: why an integral??? $p(n)$ is defined on the *naturals* not the reals! A series will suffice.